# Access to the path is denied while using FileUploadControl

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am trying to save an uploaded file:

```
string SaveLocation = Server.MapPath(@"~\Data");

FileUploadControl.SaveAs(SaveLocation);
```

I have provided `Full control` permission for for both solution and target saving folder for the below user accounts:

- Network Service
- IIS_IUSRS
- ASP.NET/machine
- IUSR

I have set `<identity impersonate="false" />` in web.config.

I tried all the above but still not able to access the path:

> ERROR: Access to the path is denied

Let me know what I need to do to access the path.

Comment: Are you using IIS? What is the user the application pool is running under?

Comment: I am running in developement.. I didnot hosted in IIS

Comment: yes.. with visual studio

Comment: What is the code giving this error?

Comment: Access to the path is denied

Comment: I have added the code above

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`FileUploadControl.SaveAs`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.fileupload.saveas(v=vs.110).aspx) requires a full file name, not only the directory as you pass to it.

```
string SaveLocation = Server.MapPath(@"~\Data\somefile.png");
FileUploadControl.SaveAs(SaveLocation);
```

Make sure to change the file path every time you upload a file, or the file will be overwritten.